# Sum rows in php and rank

Tags: php

i am creating a student information system in php and the database looks as follows

```
**studentId** **Math** **English** **Science** **className**
1                 80        66         85       3p1
2                 75        83         84       3p1
3                 70        88         90       3p1
4                 50        82         50       5p3
5                 88        77         77       3p1
6                 92        97         96       3p1
```

i want to rank only the members of the className 3P1 in using php. the sql statement below will do the ranking fine in phpmyadmin when the following are included

```
SET @myclassName:=0;
SET @myRank:= 0;
SET @myNextRank:= 0;
SET @myTotals:= 0;
```

However when i convert it to php and use it in php the ranks generated are inconsistent. everytime i reload the page the ranks also change. how do i include the

```
SET @myclassName:=0;
SET @myRank:= 0;
SET @myNextRank:= 0;
SET @myTotals:= 0;
```

in the query in php.

```
<?php 

$StudentMarkz = "SELECT X.*,
                        @myRank:=CASE WHEN @myclassName <> className
                                           THEN @myNextRank:=1
                                      WHEN @myTotals <> totals
                                           THEN @myRank:=@myNextRank
                                      ELSE @myRank
                                 END AS Rank,
                        @myclassName:=className AS myclassName,
                        @myTotals:=totals AS myTotals,
                        @myNextRank:=@myNextRank+1 AS myNextRank
                   FROM ( SELECT studentmarkstable.studentId,surname, firstName,
                                 Math,
                                 English,
                                 Science,
                                 SocialStudies,
                                 studentmarkstable.className,
                                 Math + English + Science + SocialStudies AS totals
                            FROM studentmarkstable, student 
                           WHERE student.studentId=studentmarkstable.studentId 
                             AND studentmarkstable.className='3P1' 
                           ORDER BY className ASC,
                                    6 DESC
                        ) X";
$marksQuery = mysql_query($StudentMarkz) or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

if i use $marksQuery = mysqli_multi_query($StudentMarkz) or die (mysql_error()); i get an error.

thank you in advance

Comment: Any particular flavour of database? because I'd use different queries to do it in MySQL or in Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. here's a solution for MySQL, as that's probably the most commonly used database among PHP scripters:

```
SET @myClass:=0;
SET @myRank:= 0;
SET @myTotals:= 0;
SELECT X.*,
        @myRank:=CASE WHEN @myClass <> class 
                           THEN 1
                      WHEN @myTotals <> totals 
                           THEN @myRank+1
                      ELSE @myRank
                 END AS Rank,
        @myClass:=class AS myClass,
        @myTotals:=totals AS myTotals
  FROM ( SELECT studentId,
                Math,
                English,
                Science,
                Class,
                Math + English + Science AS totals
           FROM studentGrades
          ORDER BY 5 ASC,
                   6 DESC
       ) X
```

gives:

```
studentId  Math  English  Science  Class  totals  Rank  myClass  myTotals
2          75    83       84       3p1    242     1     3p1      242
5          88    77       77       3p1    242     1     3p1      242
1          80    66       85       3p1    231     2     3p1      231
6          92    97       96       5p2    285     1     5p2      285
3          70    88       90       5p2    248     2     5p2      248
4          50    82       50       5p2    182     3     5p2      182
```

with no gaps in the ranks

**EDIT**

If you want subsequent student rank positions to be maintained after several students with the same rank (e.g. 1,2,2,4 rather than 1,2,2,3), then use the following:

```
SET @myClass:=0;
SET @myRank:= 0;
SET @myNextRank:= 0;
SET @myTotals:= 0;
SELECT X.*,
        @myRank:=CASE WHEN @myClass <> class 
                           THEN @myNextRank:=1
                      WHEN @myTotals <> totals 
                           THEN @myRank:=@myNextRank
                      ELSE @myRank
                 END AS Rank,
        @myClass:=class AS myClass,
        @myTotals:=totals AS myTotals,
        @myNextRank:=@myNextRank+1 AS myNextRank
  FROM ( SELECT studentId,
                Math,
                English,
                Science,
                Class,
                Math + English + Science AS totals
           FROM studentGrades
          ORDER BY 5 ASC,
                   6 DESC
       ) X
```

gives

```
studentId  Math  English  Science  Class  totals  Rank  myClass  myTotals  myNextRank
2          75    83       84       3p1    242     1     3p1      242       2
5          88    77       77       3p1    242     1     3p1      242       3
1          80    66       85       3p1    231     3     3p1      231       4
6          92    97       96       5p2    285     1     5p2      285       2
3          70    88       90       5p2    248     2     5p2      248       3
4          50    82       50       5p2    182     3     5p2      182       4
```

with gaps in the ranks

Comment: @Mark Baker the calculation of totals seem to be working however i am getting a [BLOB - 0B] note on the column for rank. i would also appreciate if the ranking could be done per class. whereby you can have an student being ranked no. 1 in class 3P1 and another different student being ranked No. 1 in 5P1.

Comment: If you work through the logic of how this should be calculating rank, you'll see that it should be rated by class.. that's why it's resetting the rank to 1 WHEN @myClass <> class.

Comment: I have no idea why this is giving you [BLOB - 0B] for rank: I did test it in phpmyadmin before posting it, using a table I created based on your description, and the data you used in your example

Comment: @ Mark Baker i had made a silly mistake and now the script works fine. to  add on to the script if say two students share a common total eg 440 440 430 rather than having them ranked 1,1,2. how can i have them ranked 1,1,3. such that there is no position two(2)? Regards

Comment: @Mark Baker how do i initialize the Rank, mynextrank, myclass and mytotals to 0 in php like you had done in the sql statement SET @myClass:=0;
SET @myRank:= 0;
SET @myNextRank:= 0;
SET @myTotals:= 0;
SELECT X.*,.... since without this in the php code the rank being generated is wrong and keeps on changing everytime i load the page. Regards

Comment: @Mark Baker i have tried using  mysqli_multi_query bit i get the following error. mysqli_multi_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in... in essence what i am trying to do is to rank and display results of a specific class. i have slightly modified the script you posted and fixed a class i.e ...AS totals FROM studentGrades where class='3P1'but making it work in php is proving rather hectic as the ranks being generated are inconsistent. please assist.

Comment: Edit your original question, and add exactly the code that you are using to execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

This is the PHP way (of course you might use the mysql way too).

```
$sql = "SELECT studentId, Math, Engish, Science FROM table";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Request not successfull!");

$results = array();

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($adressen_query)){   
  $results[ $result['studentId'] ] = $result['Math'] + $result['Engish'] + $result['Science'];
}
// results now contains all studentIds as Keys and all added result values as value.

// sort descending
$results = arsort( $results );
```

Other approach:

You could add a new field "All" to your table and sum up all results there.
(when writing your results to the table you could also sum up the 'All'-field)
Then you can acces your data using the query and "ORDER BY"

```
SELECT 'All' FROM table ORDER BY 'All' DESC;
```

Comment: i have been completely unable to modify and use the above code, kindly assist